# Changing a PHP file Array

Tags: php, laravel

What I need to achieve is very simple logically, I use Laravel framework and need my users to be able to change few settings directly from a form rather than opening the settings file which look like this :

```
<?php

return array(

    'driver' => 'gd'

);
```

So the question would be how to access a php array file based on key, an update the value ?

Comment: Are these setting user specific? Meaning that there can be more than one user working with your app and they can each have their own configuration file with their custom value?

Comment: Bogdan, no, those settings are limited to system, only one file can exist

Answer (score 2):

After getting settings with

```
$settings = require "settings.php";
```

You can populate the form and get changes submitted back.  After you get ALL of the settings into `$settings` (not just the changed settings, all of 'em), you can write them back with

```
$php = "<?php return " . var_export($settings,true) . ";";
file_put_contents("settings.php", $php);
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but one with a mandatory warning: **make sure the input values are escaped or are otherwise whitelisted**, because that code will be evaluated and it's a very strong security concern.

Comment: `var_export` creates valid PHP with the necessary escaping for values inside of strings.  What you have in $settings going in is what you'll get back later.  Now, of course, (and beyond scope of question) what you put into $settings before saving does need whatever scrubbing necessary.